# How to create a for loop to process a multid-dimensional matrix in Python

Tags: python

Assume I have a four-dimensional matrix A(:, :, :, :). I want to update the matrix by performing some processing on it. The pseudo codes are presented as follows:

```
for ii = 1:m
    for jj = 1:n
        A = myFunction(A(:,:,jj,ii))
    end
end
```

To implement the for-loop processing in Python:

```
for ii in range(m):
    for jj in range(n):
        A = myFunction(A[:,:,jj,ii])
```

Is that correct?

Comment: To process an n-dimensional array, you need n nested loops.

Comment: can you show the code to realize the 4-D matrix?

Comment: it's the same as for 2-D, just add loops for `kk` and `ll`.

Comment: for multi-dimension matrix and these kind of loops, ndarray from numpy would be best choice.

Comment: You mean the code structure is valid in Python?  It seems I need to make the index range from 0 to max-1 and delete the two 'end' . I am new to Python programming.

Comment: @jingweimo, yes I think they mean that the logic of your pseudocode is correct. And yes, that Python implementation is a correct translation

Comment: Accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4-dimensional matrix, you should use 4 indexes:

```
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(p):
            for l in range(q):
                myFunction(A[i,j,k,l])
```

For example:

```
A = [[[[6,1],[4,3]],[[4,8],[0,9]]],[[[1,5],[3,9]],[[5,5],[2,7]]]]
s = 0
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            for l in range(2):
                s += A[i][j][k][l]
print(s)
```